# Computation of variance based on the conditional variance

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Can anyone give some advice on solving the following problem?

$X$ is distributed as $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$;

$Y \big| X > c$ is distributed as $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$;

$Z \big|\min(X, Y) >c$ is distributed as $N(g(X,Y), \sigma_3^2)$.

Here $\mu_1$, $\sigma_1$, $\mu_2$, $\sigma_2$, $\sigma_3$ are constants. How to find the variance of $Z$?

Comment: What is function $g(X,Y)$?

Comment: For this question to be answerable, you need to know something about $Z|\min(X,Y)\le c$.

Comment: If $c$ is a constant, there is too little information. You don't have any constraint on the behavior of $Z$ when $\min(X,Y) \lt c.$ However, if $c$ is arbitrary, then let $c \to -\infty.$

Comment: Thanks. c is constant. I thought it over and agree that we need to specify Z|min(X,Y)≤c.